# How can I change power options to make my system "always on"?

Tags: 12.04, suspend, screensaver, lock-screen

Power options in 12.04 system settings has only one option: "Suspend when inactive", while I can't see any obvious settings I can change so that the system is always on - without locking the screen after 10 minutes of inactivity.

How can I change power options to make my system "always on"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change lock behavior from "Brightness and Lock" settings. Just click the lock slider to turn it off:

[image]

Comment: "Brightness and Lock"? Who would thought to look there for power option. I probably didn't expected to see the word "lock" besides brightness. Not that I see any brightness setting in that dialog :D

Comment: Maybe it does brightness on laptops? But the lock is still there :P  Although I agree it should be placed somewhere more obvious or just labeled Lock Settings or something.

Comment: For those looking for the Brightness and Lock feature in Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome Classic: Applications > System Tools > System Settings